# pandas date_range with (start, end) in generated list

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

How to generate list of range dates with start/end of given results

```
pd.date_range(start='2021-01-01', end='2021-06-01', freq='W').strftime("%Y-%b").tolist()
```

produces

```
['2021-Jan', '2021-Feb', '2021-Mar', '2021-Apr', '2021-May', '2021-Jun']
```

I'd like to know how to get

```
[{
   '2021-Jan' : {
       'start': ephoch from start period(UNIX),
       'end': epoch from end period(UNIX)
   },
   {
   '2021-Feb' : {
       'start': ephoch from start period(UNIX),
       'end': epoch from end period(UNIX)
   },
   ...
   ...
}]
```

So that when we change the frequency argument of the date_range function, the start / end of periods are calculated (such as weeks, days for example). I know that the to_list() does not the job.

Comment: What exactly is `ephoch from start period`, is it UNIX timestamp or what?

Comment: sorry, this got confusing. I edited the question. What I need is the UNIX value.